# How to a class with generics with an inline refied function

Tags: kotlin, generics, inline, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

If I have a class like the following:

```
class SimpleClass {
    var test: Int = 1
}
```

I can do something like this:

```
inline fun <reified T : SimpleClass> myFunction1(): T {
        //Do something with T
}
```

But if I have a class with generics:

```
class ComplexClass<T> {
    var test: T? = null
}
```

How can I do the same?

The following doesn't work:

```
inline fun <reified T : ComplexClass<C>> myFunction2(): T {
        //Do something with T
        //Do something with C
}
```

How can I do it?

[Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/Tr1SchxA) is a more complex example, if needed.

Comment: `reified` is a modifier for inline functions. Nothing more.

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically? Do you have a concrete example?

Comment: @Joffrey I want to use `myFunction2` in a class with a variable return type, and this class use generics. [Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/Tr1SchxA) is a more complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at your example

```
class Mediator {
    //It does't work! My question is about this function.
    inline fun <reified T : Container<C>> mediate(string: String): T {
        if (C::class == Child1::class)
            //Do something
        if (C::class == Child2::class)
            //Do something else
    }
} 

class UseExample : Mediator() {

    fun example1(): Container<Child1> {
        return mediate("test1") // your mediate function does not take
        // any parameters to determine the generic type
    }

    fun example2(): Container<Child2> {
        return mediate("test2")
    }
}
```

To perform something with the type `C` which is used to create `Container<C>` and perform something with the result type which you represent as `T : Container<C>` you only need to know the `C`. Since `reified` can only be used to keep the type if it is known during the compile time at the call site, rewrite your function signature like this.

```
inline fun <reified C> mediate(string: String): Container<C> {
   // now you know the C and you know the T which is Container<C>
   if (C::class == Child1::class) ...
   // Since T depends on C, you can only check the C type to perform logic
}
```

Use it like following

```
fun example1(): Container<Child1> {
    return mediate<Child1>("test") // Note that know your C 
    // type is known at the function call therefore compiler 
    // can substitute it with exact type
}
```

Here is my minimal example from Kotlin Playground

```
class Container<T>(t: T) {
    val smth : T = t
}

class Mediator {
    inline fun <reified C> mediate(string: String): Container<C> {
         if (C::class == Int::class) {
             println("Int")
             return Container<Int>(1) as Container<C>
         }

         throw IllegalStateException("Yopta")
     }
}


fun main() {
    val m = Mediator()

    m.mediate<Int>("ABC") // Output is "Int"
}
```

Comment: It works as I wanted, thanks. Further addition: what if the `T` in `Container<T>` is a `Array<Child1>`? Ho can I get `Child1` instead of `Array` in the mediate function? The check `C::class == Array::class` fails.

Comment: `Array<Child>` will have combined `::class`. So probably `Array<Child>::class` will do the work. If it will not, try by checking element's type