# Check if generic is an array with inline function

Tags: arrays, kotlin, class, generics

How can I check if a Generic is an Array using an inline function?

I tried with the [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74851007/3185964):

```
class Mediator {
    inline fun <reified C> mediate(string: String): Container<C> {
         if (C::class == Int::class) {
             //It works
         }
         else if (C::class == Array::class) {
             //It doesn't work!
         }
         throw IllegalStateException("Yopta")
     }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Maybe because it can be `Array<Whatever>`?

How can I do it?

Comment: @Alex.T Yes it works: if `C` is an `Int` it enters in the `if`, but it doesn't work for the `Array`. You can find a more complete code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74849343/how-to-a-class-with-generics-with-an-inline-refied-function/74851007#74851007) (the last piece of code at the end of the answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to collections where for example `List<String>` and `List<Int>` are internally represented by the same class `List`, in arrays the type parameter is a part of the type itself. That means `Array<String>` and `Array<Int>` are internally represented as different types and as far as I know, they don't have a common super type.

I don't know a pure Kotlin solution to check if a class is an array. It seems to me like an overlook in the design of the reflection API. If you don't mind using the Java reflection, you can do it like this:

```kotlin
else if (C::class.java.isArray) {
```

**Update**

There is one interesting fact here. In the Kotlin type system we could consider `Array<out Any?>` to be a supertype of all arrays. For example, we can upcast to it without an explicit cast operator:

```kotlin
val intArray = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
val arr: Array<out Any?> = intArray
```

However, for the reflection API these two types are entirely different:

```kotlin
// false
println(Array<Int>::class.isSubclassOf(Array<out Any?>::class))
```

I assume this is due to how arrays where implemented in Java. I'm not even sure if it would be technically possible to return `true` in the code above. Still, it is concerning it provides a different result than the type system at a compile time and it doesn't even produce a warning.

Answer (score 2):

Actual answer that solves the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74854069/9940820).

Since broot added an actual answer I'll just leave this here as a note as to how we can see that he is right basically.

If we make the call like this:

```
Mediator().mediate<Array<Int>>("")
```

Adding a simple check inside the function like this makes it a bit confusing as to why they are not equal.

```
println(C::class) //class Kotlin.Array
println(Array:class) //class Kotlin.Array
```

But doing the same for the underlying java class shows that they are not really the same object.

```
println(C::class.java) //class [Ljava.lang.Integer
println(Array:class.java) //class [Ljava.lang.Object
```

So changing the statement to:

```
if(C::class.java == Array<Int>::class.java)
```

Will make the example work ... for `Int` only. All other "infinite" possibilities will have to be added manually. Not an issue if you just want to check `Array<X>` only, but definitely not generic.